# Android/Java: How to reference from a class to the MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, class

Sorry for the question, probably it is answered within a few minutes.
I'm new to Android App development and have been searching for an answer for about 2 hours, but I don't find a solution.

So, this is my problem:
I created a MainActivity with a very simple layout, only one ToggleButton to start/stop some sound. I got it working with calling the MediaPlayer from within the MainActivity-Class.
Now I want to put the MediaPlayer-Handling into a separate class, such that it can be called from a widget as well.
When rising a Toast or calling a MediaPlayer-Method, I need to refer to the MainActivity, which was (in the MainActivity itself) "this".
But I don't know how to refer to the instance of the MainActivity.

The code is as follows:

```
package com.heavyloadreverse;

//import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
//import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Sound snd;
    private ToggleButton btn;   

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_OnOff);
        snd = new Sound();
        snd.mp_create(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(View v) {       
        // Perform action on clicks
        if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()) {            
            snd.mp_start();
        } else {            
            snd.mp_stop();
        }
    }

    /*********************************************************************************
    public void mp_create() {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.truckreverse);
    }

    public void mp_start () {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // start the sound  
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void mp_stop () {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.stop, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // stop the sound
        mp.stop();
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void mp_init() {
        btn.setChecked(false); 
    }
    **********************************************************************************/

    public void btn_init() {
        btn.setChecked(false); 
    }   

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();      
        btn_init();     
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        btn_init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        snd.mp_stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        snd.mp_stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy(); 
        snd.mp_stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);      
    }

}
```

The class for the MediaPlayer-Handling:

```
package com.heavyloadreverse;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Application;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.heavyloadreverse.R;

public class Sound extends Application {

    private MediaPlayer mp; 

    public void mp_create (MainActivity main) {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.truckreverse); 
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void mp_start () {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // start the sound  
        try {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void mp_stop () {
        //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.stop, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        try {
            // stop the sound
            mp.stop();
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**

--> raises a runtime-error when executing:

--> *03-12 20:23:18.412: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heavyloadreverse/com.heavyloadreverse.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException*

**Toast.makeText(main.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**

--> error in code:

--> *Multiple markers at this line
    - main cannot be resolved to a type
    - Line breakpoint:Sound [line: 15] - 
     mp_create(MainActivity)*

**Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**

--> error in code:

--> *No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope*

What do I have to do in order to make the Toast- and MediaPlayer-Calls in "Sound.java" working?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Sven

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Add 'Context' as a parameter on 'Sound'

```
public class Sound{
    private Context mContext;
    Sound(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    ...
    Toast.makeText(mContext, text, length).show();
    ...
}
```

When you create `Sound` from activity you will do it like `new Sound(this);`

**Option 2**

Define an interface in Sound to provide callbacks

```
public class Sound {
    interface OnSoundListener{
        public void onSoundStarted();
        public void onSoundStopped();
    }
}
```

And your main activity will look like

```
public class MainActivity implements Sound.OnSoundListener{
    @Override
    public void onSoundStarted(){
        //your toast here
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer the second one, that way you can separate logic from UI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this work, only an idea.

Firs of all extend your Sound class from your MainActivity

```
public class Sound extends MainActivity {
```

second, this is the code I use for Toast to work:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your Text Here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I think, I tried this yesterday. Run into some error as well, but I'm gonna give it a shot when I'm home tonight. Thanks..

Comment: This is a really bad idea, doing this way you will introduce a new activity (with all needed objects) into the system needing more resources than required.

Answer (score 0):

For Toast this is what you need to do:

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Hello toast", 2000);

     toast.show();
```

Check this [tutorial](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-popup-messages-using-toast.html) tutorial if it helps.

Comment: This works, if i call Toast from within the MainActivity.
If I call it from within the Sound-class, I get a runtime-error as I mentioned above. The reference to "this" is the problem.

Comment: I see, you may try getApplicationContext() instead of this. I am not infront of computer to validate this, but you may give a try.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot when I'm home tonight. Thanks.